# Retrieve customizer value using ajax or customizer api and print the value in theme

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, theme-customizer

one of my clients have Branches. one located in new york another in los angeles and etc...

in the live site we print new york phone and address(from the customizer) as default.

what i need is to create drop down menu with all the Branches in the live site.

when the user will select "los angeles" for example, the phone number and the address will be updated based on customizer value (for each Branch i have field with phone and address).

**in php i can simaple get the value by:**

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'newyork_phone' );
```

the question is how can retrieve all the values i need from the customizer, based on user choose?

```
(function($){
    wp.customize("newyork_phone", function(value) {
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**i tried to play with this code, but id did not get how can i get the "value" and print this in my theme?**

in the theme customizer i am using this code:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'newyork_phone', 
    array(
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    'newyork_phone',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Phone', 'test-admin' ),
        'section' => 'title_tagline', 
        'settings' => 'newyork_phone', 
        'priority'    => 15,
        'type' => 'text'
    )
 );
```

in the header.php i am using:

```
<select name="branches">
  <option value="newyork">new york</option>
  <option value="losangeles">los angeles</option>
</select>
```

then in jQuery i can get the value by:

```
$('select[name=branches]').val()
```

**example:**
option one is "new york"

i want to get values:

newyork_phone

newyork_adress

etc...

option two is "los angeles"

losangeles_phone

losangeles_adress

and show the values in my theme.

Comment: Do you want to update the values in the customizer theme preview or in the live site once the customizer options have been saved?

Comment: Hi @cybmeta i want to update the values in the live site once the customizer options have been saved.

Comment: Are you [defining the setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting) as `theme_mod` type or `option` type?

Comment: @cybmeta i have updated my question.

Comment: Hi @cybmeta can you help me with that?

Comment: I could, but I'm not sure what you really need. Your question is not very clear. Try to explain better. What is the `<select>` element suppose to do?

Comment: Hi @cybmeta i have full updated my question. Thanks

Comment: no one know how to work with theme customizer using ajax or JS API?

Comment: You have tried with `wp.customize` (JS), which is not available if you are not in theme customizer screen. Have you tried using [Ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)? If yes, where do you have problems? If no, try it and come back if you need help.